# Join edges in graph and recalculate the branch cost

Tags: c++, graph, nodes, mex, treenode

I build a graph and each step has a cost/weight and a position. In the end i want to join together all edges, which are epsilon distance (in position) from each other. If I do that I only want to keep the ones with smaller cost/weight. If I join a node at start, all edges on the more expensive branch get cheaper by the difference in cost. How can I propagate this to the ends of the branches?

```
  1   Position graph       Pos  Cost
 / \                        1   0
2  2.2                      2   2
|    \                     2.2  1          
5     \                     5   cost(2)+1 = 3
       7                    7   cost(2.2)+2.5 = 3.5
```

Here nodes at position 2 and 2.2 are < 1 distance from each other so they should be joined. The nodes at 7 and 5 have to have their cost recalculated.
Taking the cheaper node the cost for `2'` is 1 now. However the cost for 5 changes to `cost(5)+cost(2.2)-cost(2) = 2`. And the new graph:

```
  1          Pos  Cost
  |           1    0
 2.2         2.2   1
 / \          5    2
5   7         7   3.5
```

My questions are the following:
How do I save the childs of a node best? (since the number is variying I don't really know a good solution).
How do I calculate the minimal costs for each position in the joined paths?

At the moment I have the graph in the other direction (saving the parent). This way I really have no clue how I could have efficient joining, since this would cause huge recursions. It's written in `C++` as `struct{int parent; double pos; double cost}`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what kind of graph do you have (tree, acyclic, anything else, unrestricted) ?

Comment: As already stated i save the parent node for each node, which makes it a tree I guess. However if the goal or start is the "mother node" can be changed. The restriction is, that each node is only a valid extention in it's region. I can grow one from any node and save the new node somehow.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using a tree/graph library ( eg. [Boost Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) ) instead of reinventing the wheel ? If you feel you aren't I'd suggest a class like `struct {double pos; double cost; int parent; int first_child; int left_sibling; int right_sibling }`. Generally speaking a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) supporting union-find operation would probably suit your objectives best.

Comment: What would I do with the siblings? Could you complete your suggestion a little bit please? The disjoint tree set as described by wikipedia are kind of what I thought of. I'd compare if two positions are within epsilon and if so, I'd use the cheapest parent for both. However this changes the cost of all downstream nodes. Therefore I have to be careful where I start joining nodes (or I coulds choose more expensive ones).
Since I write in matlab-mex-C for the first time, idk how to use libs. I'll investigate. The question is however which form and how to identify costs.